# How to set precision of decimal number for whole application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with selecting number e.g. 16.00 in view. When I don't use method number_with_precision, there is 16.0. How to set in application helper selecting all decimal number properly?

Comment: There is no configuration option for that AFAIK. You could monkey-patch `Numeric#to_s`.

Comment: Also, note that there is string interpolation: `'%.2f' % 16` will yield `'16.00'`.

Comment: @Raffael: That's just a call to the `String#%` method, interpolation is something else (i.e. `" .... #{expr} ... "`).

Comment: You are of course right, the % notation I mentioned is closer to `Kernel#sprintf` than to string interpolation. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rafael said you can do monkey patch for it.

Here is an example:

```
# config/initializers/numeric.rb

class Numeric
  def nice
    sprintf("%.2f", self)
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= @number.nice %>
```